# writing an structure to a binary file and reading it

Tags: c++, file, struct

I'm writing a c++ program in Linux in which I have a structure named list:

```
struct list{

    char names[20][20];
    int prices[20];
    int Num_Of_Merchandise;
};
```

I make an structure and initialize its arrays and integer, then I write it to a file. After that I read the structure again and make some changes:

```
list new_list;

ifstream ml("Desktop:\\Mlist.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);

if(ml){
    ml.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&new_list),sizeof(new_list));
}   

int m,i;
cout<<"1-add\n2-remove\n";
cin>>m;
if(m==1){
    cout<< "enter the name of new merchandise:\n";
    cin>>new_list.names[new_list.Num_Of_Merchandise];
    cout<< "enter the price of new merchandise:\n";
    int newPrice;
    cin>>newPrice;  
    new_list.prices[new_list.Num_Of_Merchandise]=newPrice;
    new_list.Num_Of_Merchandise++;
}
```

But then when I read the file in another program (after changes), it gives segmentation fault. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So it's worth noting that we need to see the code writing out too. I suspect the Compiler is doing some magic to make your array of arrays work. And moreover that you're not making sure the binary data in the file matches the layout and bitness of the struct.

Comment: Can I suggest you look into boost::serialisation?

Comment: Also, consider using Google Protobuf

Comment: You want to serialise binary structures properly. Which means writing each member out with known endianness, size, and, for strings, character encoding and end of string.

Answer (score 0):

> But then when I read the file in another program (after changes), it gives segmentation fault.

Your example code show only reading, there is no writing - so your midifications are not persisted.

If you have a writing code anyway then its hard to tell without seeing your `another program` code. If you adhere to its specification for a file format, then I can only recomend to make sure alignment is not an issue here, to do this add `#pragma pack` which will work on both MSVC and gcc:

```
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
struct list{
    char names[20][20];
    int prices[20];
    int Num_Of_Merchandise;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```